# Kohana 3.2 - phpBB library - working with abstract methods

Tags: php, include, kohana, kohana-3, abstract

I'm attempting to implement a phpBB library into Kohana.

I have created a vendor folder in my module and load the library like this and initialise it:

```
require_once Kohana::find_file('vendor/phpbb_library', 'phpbb_library');
$phpbb = new Phpbb_library();
```

However once the library starts attempting to include the phpBB files:

```
// Include needed files
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'config.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_privmsgs.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_posting.' . $phpEx);
```

I then receive the following error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class user contains 5 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Kohana_Session::_read, Kohana_Session::_regenerate, Kohana_Session::_write, ...)
```

Now the included files are those used by phpBB so obviously I can't just go modifying them.

---

**Solved 01/02/2012**

Following the solution proposed by [Michal M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108878/michal-m) I have created my own versions of the Kohana Session class and saved them in a module. The files I had to copy, rename and edit were:

```
/system/classes/session.php
/system/classes/session/cookie.php
/system/classes/session/exception.php
/system/classes/session/native.php

/system/classes/kohana/session.php
/system/classes/kohana/session/cookie.php
/system/classes/kohana/session/exception.php
/system/classes/kohana/session/native.php
```

In all files the main edits involved changing class names `Session` to `MySiteSession` and `Kohana_Session` to `Kohana_MySite_Session`. Although there were a few usages of the variables in the `/system/classes/kohana` files which also needed the name change.

Now to use the session I simply call `MySiteSession::instance()`.

PHPBB now works as an include as I am no longer using the Session class.

Comment: The error is being triggered because phpBB and Kohana both have a Session class. There is no solution for this.

Comment: How can there be no solution? CodeIgniter allows for it to work: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/phpBB3_library I thought Kohana was an offset of the CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: Did you actually succeeded on bridge implementation? Could you please share sources? Thanks

Comment: @zdmytriv Yes, I managed to do what Michal M suggested and setup my own class for handling sessions which I now use instead of the default Session class. This removed the conflict between the two systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI has different class naming. All CI classes begin with `CI_` while Kohana doesn't use any prefixes*.

The only solution I can think of for you would be to refactor Kohana Session class (rename it everywhere) or do it with phpBB libraries. Neither is ideal though.

---

*) Just to clarify, Kohana does use `Kohana_`, but all their classes are extended by classes without prefixes.

Comment: I have created a new session class and used it throughout the site. There is one place in the system which also uses `Session::instance()` in the `system/classes/kohana/security` file. Which I don't know if I should change or not. Will try extending it.

Comment: Confirmed this worked and added full explanation in original question.